# Running node-red flow with a client request

Tags: client-server, dialogflow-es, node-red

I  have a node-red flow. I want to run the flow **without clicking any trigger** node like inject. I want to run the flow **with a client request** from the dialogflow bot. Is there anyone who has encountered with this problem?

Comment: Any of the *input* nodes can be used to start a flow (e.g. http, tcp, mqtt, file watcher, etc). What protocol does the dialogflow bot use to make a "client request"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node red has http in node. You can create an end point. It listenst from this end point. When a request send to it, it is trigered. You can use it for injecting.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. It can be helpfull for some people. The solution is like following:

The inject node sends a post request to  an end point which is **inject/inject node Id**. So when I request (POST) to the end point, the flow runs. An example of the request is like following:
http://localhost:1880/inject/585915a7.b4f89c

Answer (score -1):

In your Primary node, Instead of

`node.on('input', function (msg) {
   ......
   node.send(msg);
});`

on your .js file itself write your logic

`RED.nodes.registerType("PrimaryNode", (c)=>{
   .....
   node.send({"payload": value});
})`

This will triggered when node loads, no trigger needed to start your flow.

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked.

Comment: Also you should not be sending messages as part of node initialisation as you can't be sure any other nodes in the flow are initialised at that time (this is why the inject node waits before firing at startup)